# Mysql delete constraint

Tags: mysql, constraints

I have a table with below structure :

```
    CREATE TABLE `Lm_help` (
 `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `section` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `language` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `text` text NOT NULL,
 `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `unique_help` (`section`,`language`),
 KEY `language_constraint` (`language`),
 CONSTRAINT `language_constraint` FOREIGN KEY (`language`) REFERENCES `Lm_languages` (`id`),
 CONSTRAINT `section_constraint` FOREIGN KEY (`section`) REFERENCES `Lm_help_sections` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I need to remove "unique_help" key, but I am getting foreign key constraint error.

> Due to this error I not able to remove anything among these,
>   section_constraint, language_constraint, unique_help.

Below are other tables that refer to this :

```
CREATE TABLE `Lm_languages` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
 `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1




CREATE TABLE `Lm_help_sections` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: unique_help is not a primary key, its a unique index. What error are you getting?

Comment: Cannot drop index 'language_constraint': needed in a foreign key constraint

Comment: and Cannot drop index 'unique_help': needed in a foreign key constraint

Comment: Please add the table structure of the tabls that relate to `lm_help`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem is that the `unique_help (section, language)` index is used by the `section_constraint` foreign key constraint. So you can't drop the index without dropping the constraint first.

---

One way to solve this, is to drop the foreign key constraint first, then drop the index.

Then you can add a (simple) index on `(section)` and recreate the foreign key.

All these can be done in one statement:

```
ALTER TABLE Lm_help
    DROP FOREIGN KEY section_constraint,   -- drop the FK so
    DROP INDEX unique_help,                -- the index can be dropped
                                           -- and then
    ADD INDEX section_IX (section),        -- add a new index
    ADD CONSTRAINT section_FK              -- so the FK can be recreated
        FOREIGN KEY (section) 
        REFERENCES Lm_help_sections (id)
  ;
```

Tested at **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47ef2)**

---

**Improvement**

I was wrong, no need to drop and recreate the constraint. The index can be dropped, as long a new index is created:

```
ALTER TABLE Lm_help
    DROP INDEX unique_help,
    ADD INDEX section_IX (section) 
  ;
```

Tested at **[SQL-Fiddle-2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e7f8/1)**

Comment: Thanks, that worked, I was using drop index section_constraint, this was not working but drop foreign key section_constraint worked....... Can you explain me why ???

Comment: That's the syntax (in MySQL) to drop foreign key constraints.

Answer (score 8):

```
ALTER TABLE Orders
DROP FOREIGN KEY 'language_constraint';

ALTER TABLE Orders
DROP FOREIGN KEY 'section_constraint';
```

PERFORM DELETE QUERY HERE

```
ALTER TABLE Orders
ADD CONSTRAINT `language_constraint`
FOREIGN KEY (`language`)
REFERENCES `Lm_languages` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE Orders
ADD CONSTRAINT `section_constraint`
FOREIGN KEY (`section`)
REFERENCES `Lm_help_sections` (`id`);
```

Comment: Thanks tushar that worked, but I cannot accept two answers... :)

Answer (score 2):

<strike>[As your error message suggests](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html):</strike>

> (...) in the *[table referenced by a foreign key]*, there must be an
>   index where the referenced columns are listed as the first columns in
>   the same order.

You must find the referencing table(s) and drop the foreign key constraint(s) from this (these) other table(s).

My bad, I read through your table definition too quickly. The actual problem is [the other way around](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that
>   foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan.

Either drop the `section_constraint` foreign key constraint first, or create a new index on `language` before dropping the UNIQUE constraint.

Comment: You can have a look at structure of the other tables, that I have used

Comment: My bad, please see my new anwer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a stored procedure that you can call to drop a foreign key prior to calling the create sql. I modified an answer to a similar question about DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Answered by: https://stackoverflow.com/users/166161/thomas-paine

sample call:

```
CALL DropForeignKey (DATABASE(), 'tablename', 'keyname');
```

Procedure:

```
DELIMITER ;

/* DROP_FOREIGN_KEY */
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS DropForeignKey;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE DropForeignKey(
IN param_schema VARCHAR(100),
IN param_table_name VARCHAR(100),
IN param_constraint_name VARCHAR(100)
) 

BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
    WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME=param_constraint_name AND TABLE_NAME=param_table_name AND TABLE_SCHEMA = param_schema
    )
    THEN
        set @paramTable = param_table_name ;

    set @ParamConstraintName = param_constraint_name ;
    set @ParamSchema = param_schema;
    /* Create the full statement to execute */
    set @StatementToExecute = concat('ALTER TABLE `',@ParamSchema,'`.`',@paramTable,'` DROP FOREIGN KEY `',@ParamConstraintName,'` ');
    /* Prepare and execute the statement that was built */
    prepare DynamicStatement from @StatementToExecute ;
    execute DynamicStatement ;
    /* Cleanup the prepared statement */
    deallocate prepare DynamicStatement ;

END IF;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```